# Contents of /var/run persist across reboots

Tags: root-filesystem

Does it mean my distro is broken (it's a custom distro for a board I'm using, it could easily be buggy)? Can I tweak this behaviour?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that sounds broken. The [Filesystem Hierarchy Standard](http://www.pathname.com/fhs/pub/fhs-2.3.html#VARRUNRUNTIMEVARIABLEDATA) mandates that

> This directory contains system information data describing the system
>   since it was booted. Files under this directory must be cleared
>   (removed or truncated as appropriate) at the beginning of the boot
>   process.

Answer (score 0):

Unless `/var/run` is a RAM disk, there is no reason that rebooting will affect any of its contents at all.  Most well-behaved applications that drop files there will (try to) clean up after themselves, but other than its generalized use-case there is nothing special about that directory on your filesystem as compared to most others.

Comment: I don't believe that's true. See Ulrich's answer. The contents of /var/run are supposed to be deleted not just due to cooperating well-behaved applications. For instance, `cron` puts `crond.reboot` there, and never deletes it, relying on this behaviour of the directory.

Comment: That describes what is _supposed_ to happen in that directory.  The only way this can be (nearly) guaranteed to be the case is if it is a RAM disk or other ephemeral filesystem.  It is incumbent on applications that write to that location to clean up after themselves.

Comment: You are right about the ephemeral filesystem part. And /var/run should _by spec_ be such. One way to do that is to implment it as a symlink to /run, which is in turn a mount of tmpfs. But no, it's not incumbent on apps to clean after themselves, precisely because the contents should, as per OS spec, disappear on reboot.

Comment: The way I usually think of it as a user/admin is that I can expect that the contents of `/tmp` _shall_ be removed at shutdown, and that I _must not rely_ on anything in `{/var,/run}` being there after shutdown.  I generally sanity-check anything I read from `/var/run' (PID file?  Use `kill -0` to check that PID actually exists, for instance) just in case it's a stale or orphaned file.